# java.awt.Desktop.browse() method issue

Tags: java, url, browser

When we use Desktop.browse method to open a url in Internet Explorer, then it overrides the current web page in the browser. Hence if user was doing anything critical in current page in browser, then its all lost.

This does not happen in IE8 and firefox. But the problem is there in IE6.

Has anybody found a fix for this problem in IE6.

Comment: isn't this dependent of the settings in the explorer? ('open urls in current window' or something like this)

Comment: do u know where is this setting...i have not actuall even searched yet..:)..if u do know already pls do post:)

Comment: @karussell...i got it...It was in Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Reuse Windows for shortcuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the settings in IE to open a new window.
As you pointed out the settings is available in

Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Reuse Windows for shortcuts

Comment: @karussel....can u update the following path in your answer: Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Reuse Windows for shortcuts ....so i could select your answer as the right answer:)