# Use java.awt.Desktop on client/server application for open browser on client

Tags: java, api, browser, desktop

I'm trying to use the desktop class in client/server application.

I want the default browser to open on the client side when the client clicks on a button. What happens is that the browser opens on the server. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you call any `Desktop` method on the server, then of course the reaction will occur on the server.

If you want a window to pop up on the client, then call the method on the client.

What kind of client are you using?

If you're using a rich Java client, then that change should be relatively easy.

Comment: I have an application that run in JBoss, and clients use throught internet (by IP). When client use the application this should run in client machine and not in server machine.

Comment: @Duarte: what client are you using? Did you write that yourself? Is the client using a web browser?

Comment: yes, it was write for me! For access to client you use an link that download a "*.jnlp" from server and run the application.

Answer (score -1):

Its browser specific,

Fiddle with the following setting, in IE:

Change the settings in IE to open a new window. As you pointed out the settings is available in

```
Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Reuse Windows for shortcuts
```

Answer (score -2):

Its browser specific,

Fiddle with the following setting, in IE:

Change the settings in IE to open a new window. As you pointed out the settings is available in

```
Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Reuse Windows for shortcuts
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131916/java-awt-desktop-browse-method-issue)

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the question as far as I see.